# EasyPHP (DevServer 14.1 VC11) unexpected end of mysql

Tags: windows-10, mysql, easyphp

I installed EasyPHP because i need it for school, however when I start it i get an error called "unexpected end of mysql" and i can't start MySQL.

I tried to change some option in the file my.ini but i still have this error.

Error log:

```
2019-11-02 14:03:51 9612 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-11-02 14:03:51 2480 InnoDB: Warning: Setting innodb_use_sys_malloc to FALSE is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2019-11-02 14:03:51 9612 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-11-02 14:03:51 9612 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2019-11-02 14:03:51 9612 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-11-02 14:03:51 9612 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 20.0M
2019-11-02 14:03:51 9612 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-02 14:03:51 9612 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-11-02 14:03:51 2480  InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2019-11-02 14:03:51 9612 [ERROR] InnoDB: File D:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\data\ib_logfile0: 'aio read' returned OS error 187. Cannot continue operation
```

Does anyone can help me to fix it?

Comment: Can you check if the `D:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\mysql\data\ib_logfile0` File is writeable?

Comment: Try to add this line to `my.ini`: `innodb_flush_method=normal`.

Comment: @harrymc thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked: Add this line to `my.ini`:

```
innodb_flush_method=normal
```